# JavaScript Chart.JS - issue keeping charts in two rows, instead everything in stacked into one column

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I'm trying to work JavaScript and Chart.JS for data visualization work.  I've been working off a great template (see below), however I actually reduced the size of the charts, yet everything is still displaying in one column.  My desired output would be two rows: Row 1: Line Graph and Bar Graph, Row 2: 3 Donut charts.  This is how it is displayed in the example I worked off of, however I wanted to make my charts a little smaller.  I'm clearly missing something, but with what I need help.  Bottom line, what do I need to do to make an output of two rows (1 with line and bar graph, and 1 with the 3 donut charts like my example?

Template I was using: https://www.codeply.com/go/3l6UhaQEhq/bootstrap-4-chartjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
     <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col">
                <h4>Bootstrap 4 Chart.js</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row my-2">
            <div class="col-md-6 py-1">
                <div class="card" style="width: 30rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <canvas id="chLine"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 py-1">
                <div class="card" style="width: 30rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <canvas id="chBar"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-2">
            <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <canvas id="chDonut1"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <canvas id="chDonut2"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <canvas id="chDonut3"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
/* chart.js chart examples */

// chart colors
var colors = ['#007bff','#28a745','#333333','#c3e6cb','#dc3545','#6c757d'];

/* large line chart */
var chLine = document.getElementById("chLine");
var chartData = {
  labels: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [589, 445, 483, 503, 689, 692, 634],
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: colors[0],
    borderWidth: 4,
    pointBackgroundColor: colors[0]
  }
//   {
//     data: [639, 465, 493, 478, 589, 632, 674],
//     backgroundColor: colors[3],
//     borderColor: colors[1],
//     borderWidth: 4,
//     pointBackgroundColor: colors[1]
//   }
  ]
};
if (chLine) {
  new Chart(chLine, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    responsive: true
  }
  });
}

/* large pie/donut chart */
var chPie = document.getElementById("chPie");
if (chPie) {
  new Chart(chPie, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: ['Desktop', 'Phone', 'Tablet', 'Unknown'],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: [colors[1],colors[0],colors[2],colors[5]],
          borderWidth: 0,
          data: [50, 40, 15, 5]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [{
      beforeDraw: function(chart) {
        var width = chart.chart.width,
            height = chart.chart.height,
            ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        ctx.restore();
        var fontSize = (height / 70).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        var text = chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[0] + "%",
            textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
            textY = height / 2;
        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
        ctx.save();
      }
    }],
    options: {layout:{padding:0}, legend:{display:false}, cutoutPercentage: 80}
  });
}

/* bar chart */
var chBar = document.getElementById("chBar");
if (chBar) {
  new Chart(chBar, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [589, 445, 483, 503, 689, 692, 634],
      backgroundColor: colors[0]
    },
    {
      data: [639, 465, 493, 478, 589, 632, 674],
      backgroundColor: colors[1]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        barPercentage: 0.4,
        categoryPercentage: 0.5
      }]
    }
  }
  });
}

/* 3 donut charts */
var donutOptions = {
  cutoutPercentage: 85,
  legend: {position:'bottom', padding:5, labels: {pointStyle:'circle', usePointStyle:true}}
};

// donut 1
var chDonutData1 = {
    labels: ['Bootstrap', 'Popper', 'Other'],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [74, 11, 40]
      }
    ]
};

var chDonut1 = document.getElementById("chDonut1");
if (chDonut1) {
  new Chart(chDonut1, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: chDonutData1,
      options: donutOptions
  });
}

// donut 2
var chDonutData2 = {
    labels: ['Wips', 'Pops', 'Dags'],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [40, 45, 30]
      }
    ]
};
var chDonut2 = document.getElementById("chDonut2");
if (chDonut2) {
  new Chart(chDonut2, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: chDonutData2,
      options: donutOptions
  });
}

// donut 3
var chDonutData3 = {
    labels: ['Angular', 'React', 'Other'],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [21, 45, 55, 33]
      }
    ]
};
var chDonut3 = document.getElementById("chDonut3");
if (chDonut3) {
  new Chart(chDonut3, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: chDonutData3,
      options: donutOptions
  });
}

/* 3 line charts */
var lineOptions = {
    legend:{display:false},
    tooltips:{interest:false,bodyFontSize:11,titleFontSize:11},
    scales:{
        xAxes:[
            {
                ticks:{
                    display:false
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display:false,
                    drawBorder:false
                }
            }
        ],
        yAxes:[{display:false}]
    },
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 6,
            right: 6,
            top: 4,
            bottom: 6
        }
    }
};

var chLine1 = document.getElementById("chLine1");
if (chLine1) {
  new Chart(chLine1, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May'],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
              borderColor:'#ffffff',
              data: [10, 11, 4, 11, 4],
              fill: false
            }
          ]
      },
      options: lineOptions
  });
}
var chLine2 = document.getElementById("chLine2");
if (chLine2) {
  new Chart(chLine2, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['A','B','C','D','E'],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
              borderColor:'#ffffff',
              data: [4, 5, 7, 13, 12],
              fill: false
            }
          ]
      },
      options: lineOptions
  });
}

var chLine3 = document.getElementById("chLine3");
if (chLine3) {
  new Chart(chLine3, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['Pos','Neg','Nue','Other','Unknown'],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
              borderColor:'#ffffff',
              data: [13, 15, 10, 9, 14],
              fill: false
            }
          ]
      },
      options: lineOptions
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the needed thing are the external bootstrap stuff. Running the snippet below in JSFiddle will give me the needed result, right?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>

     <div class="container">
         <div class="row my-3">
                <div class="col">
                    <h4>Bootstrap 4 Chart.js</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row my-2">
                <div class="col-md-6 py-1">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 30rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <canvas id="chLine"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 py-1">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 30rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <canvas id="chBar"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row py-2">
                <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <canvas id="chDonut1"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <canvas id="chDonut2"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <canvas id="chDonut3"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>

    <script>
    /* chart.js chart examples */

    // chart colors
    var colors = ['#007bff','#28a745','#333333','#c3e6cb','#dc3545','#6c757d'];

    /* large line chart */
    var chLine = document.getElementById("chLine");
    var chartData = {
      labels: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
      datasets: [{
        data: [589, 445, 483, 503, 689, 692, 634],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: colors[0],
        borderWidth: 4,
        pointBackgroundColor: colors[0]
      }
    //   {
    //     data: [639, 465, 493, 478, 589, 632, 674],
    //     backgroundColor: colors[3],
    //     borderColor: colors[1],
    //     borderWidth: 4,
    //     pointBackgroundColor: colors[1]
    //   }
      ]
    };
    if (chLine) {
      new Chart(chLine, {
      type: 'line',
      data: chartData,
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: false
            }
          }]
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        responsive: true
      }
      });
    }

    /* large pie/donut chart */
    var chPie = document.getElementById("chPie");
    if (chPie) {
      new Chart(chPie, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
          labels: ['Desktop', 'Phone', 'Tablet', 'Unknown'],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor: [colors[1],colors[0],colors[2],colors[5]],
              borderWidth: 0,
              data: [50, 40, 15, 5]
            }
          ]
        },
        plugins: [{
          beforeDraw: function(chart) {
            var width = chart.chart.width,
                height = chart.chart.height,
                ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
            ctx.restore();
            var fontSize = (height / 70).toFixed(2);
            ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            var text = chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[0] + "%",
                textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
                textY = height / 2;
            ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
            ctx.save();
          }
        }],
        options: {layout:{padding:0}, legend:{display:false}, cutoutPercentage: 80}
      });
    }

    /* bar chart */
    var chBar = document.getElementById("chBar");
    if (chBar) {
      new Chart(chBar, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
        datasets: [{
          data: [589, 445, 483, 503, 689, 692, 634],
          backgroundColor: colors[0]
        },
        {
          data: [639, 465, 493, 478, 589, 632, 674],
          backgroundColor: colors[1]
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 0.4,
            categoryPercentage: 0.5
          }]
        }
      }
      });
    }

    /* 3 donut charts */
    var donutOptions = {
      cutoutPercentage: 85,
      legend: {position:'bottom', padding:5, labels: {pointStyle:'circle', usePointStyle:true}}
    };

    // donut 1
    var chDonutData1 = {
        labels: ['Bootstrap', 'Popper', 'Other'],
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: [74, 11, 40]
          }
        ]
    };

    var chDonut1 = document.getElementById("chDonut1");
    if (chDonut1) {
      new Chart(chDonut1, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: chDonutData1,
          options: donutOptions
      });
    }

    // donut 2
    var chDonutData2 = {
        labels: ['Wips', 'Pops', 'Dags'],
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: [40, 45, 30]
          }
        ]
    };
    var chDonut2 = document.getElementById("chDonut2");
    if (chDonut2) {
      new Chart(chDonut2, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: chDonutData2,
          options: donutOptions
      });
    }

    // donut 3
    var chDonutData3 = {
        labels: ['Angular', 'React', 'Other'],
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: [21, 45, 55, 33]
          }
        ]
    };
    var chDonut3 = document.getElementById("chDonut3");
    if (chDonut3) {
      new Chart(chDonut3, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: chDonutData3,
          options: donutOptions
      });
    }

    /* 3 line charts */
    var lineOptions = {
        legend:{display:false},
        tooltips:{interest:false,bodyFontSize:11,titleFontSize:11},
        scales:{
            xAxes:[
                {
                    ticks:{
                        display:false
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display:false,
                        drawBorder:false
                    }
                }
            ],
            yAxes:[{display:false}]
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 6,
                right: 6,
                top: 4,
                bottom: 6
            }
        }
    };

    var chLine1 = document.getElementById("chLine1");
    if (chLine1) {
      new Chart(chLine1, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
              labels: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May'],
              datasets: [
                {
                  backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
                  borderColor:'#ffffff',
                  data: [10, 11, 4, 11, 4],
                  fill: false
                }
              ]
          },
          options: lineOptions
      });
    }
    var chLine2 = document.getElementById("chLine2");
    if (chLine2) {
      new Chart(chLine2, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
              labels: ['A','B','C','D','E'],
              datasets: [
                {
                  backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
                  borderColor:'#ffffff',
                  data: [4, 5, 7, 13, 12],
                  fill: false
                }
              ]
          },
          options: lineOptions
      });
    }

    var chLine3 = document.getElementById("chLine3");
    if (chLine3) {
      new Chart(chLine3, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
              labels: ['Pos','Neg','Nue','Other','Unknown'],
              datasets: [
                {
                  backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
                  borderColor:'#ffffff',
                  data: [13, 15, 10, 9, 14],
                  fill: false
                }
              ]
          },
          options: lineOptions
      });
    }
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: That did it! Thank you!